# ASP.NET MVC 4 action filter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a filter and place it on actions that need database access. This filter will dispose the current unit of work so i won't need to call it manually one or more times in one action.
I am doing this:

```
    public class DisposeUnitOfWorkAttribute :FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
        {
            IUnitOfWork currentUnitOfWork = UnitOfWork.Current;
            if (currentUnitOfWork != null)
            {
                currentUnitOfWork.Dispose();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }


    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new DisposeUnitOfWorkAttribute());
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }


        [DisposeUnitOfWork]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {            
            var user = _usersRepository.Get(x => x.Username == "jack").ToList();
            //UnitOfWork.Current.Dispose();
            return View();
        }
```

I get the exception : `The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.`

How can i correct this?

Comment: Implement the interfaces and the methods required by them..

Comment: I did implement IActionFilter.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by your code, you are trying to use the filter as a Web API filter, but adding it to a wrong filter collection in FilterConfig.cs (MVC-like)

```
The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.
```

You should add the filter to Web API global filter collection instead in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Add custom global filters

        // Handle validation errors
        config.Filters.Add(new DisposeUnitOfWorkAttribute());
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you need to inherit from `ActionFilterAttribute` not FilterAttribute

```
public class DisposeUnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   ...
}
```